# Wordpress Jquery Ajax form progress bar loading quickly after showing response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

```
jQuery('.progress', form).css('width', '0');
jQuery.ajax({

        xhr: function () {

            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                    jQuery('.progress', form).text(percentComplete + '%');
                    jQuery('.progress', form).css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: badnc_ajax.ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery("div[id='results']", form).css('display', 'block');
            jQuery("div[id='loading']", form).css('display', 'none');
            jQuery("div[id='results']", form).html(unescape(data));
        }

    });
```

This code is showing progressbar when I submit the form. Only problem is progressbar shows after receiving the response.

I mean progressbar shows after displaying the message from PHP file.

I want to show the percent counter increasing and whenever it reaches 100% then show response.

Comment: Do you want to see upload progress or download progress?

Comment: @Musa How to identify it?

Comment: `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress"...` si for upload, `xhr.addEventListener("progress"...` is for download.

Comment: @Musa It for download and I changed it to `xhr.addEventListener("progress"` but now the problem is progress bar showed after showing the response. I want to show the progress bar incrementing....

Comment: @Musa I think I want to to call php file as part of xhr. But how can I do that??? `xhr.open` is not working for me.

Comment: `xhr.open` is deprecated https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method